# Fill in placeholders in an HTML file using Java

Tags: java, html

I got an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello! <b>[NAME]%</b></p>
</body>
```

And what I got in my Java file is that:

```
String name = "John";
```

My question is:

1. How do that fill John into the [Name]% in Java?
2. After doing so, how do I convert it to a *base64-encoded* string in Java?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which java technology do you use ?

Comment: `String name = "John";` is all you have?  Have you at least attempted to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of characters that Java's regular-expression processor likes to haggle with.  I would think that if you have programmed Java before for text-processing, then the String.replace(String, String); method would accomplish what you are attempting to do.

There are three String replace methods.  Two of them, though, require regular-expressions.  Regular-expressions would expect you to "escape" the brackets that you have typed.

**Here is the text, copied from Oracle/Sun's Java documentation for: java.lang.String**

> ```
> String    replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.
>
> ```
> String    replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.
>
> ```
> String    replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given
>   regular expression with the given replacement.

**Just so you are aware - the two that say "regex" in the parameter-list would expect the regex String to follow this format for pattern-matching purposes:**

```
// Regular-Expression Programming with java.lang.String - Several "Escaped" Characters!
// ALSO NOTE: Back-slashes need to be twice-escaped!

String replacePattern = "\\[NAME\\]%";
yourText.replaceFirst(replacePattern, "John");
```

These "back-slashes from hell" are required because the Regular Expressions Processor wants you to escape the '[' and the ']' because they are key-words (reserved/special characters) to the processor's system. Please review Regular Expressions in the Java 7/8/9 documentation to understand how `String.replaceFirst` and `String.replaceAll` work vis-a-vis the regex variable.  Alternatively, if you use `String.replace`, all Java would expect is a direct character match, specifically:

```
yourText = yourText.replace("[NAME]%", "John");
```

Here is a link to Sun/Oracle's page on java.util.regex.Pattern:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

**NOTE: Answer below is copied Google's Answer about base64 Encoding.**  I personally do not quite understand your question.  Let me know if you are talking about UTF-8?  UniCode?  What do you mean by a "Base64 encoded String"?

> **What is the use of base64 encoding in Java?** Encodes the specified byte array into a String using the Base64 encoding scheme. Returns an
>   encoder instance that encodes equivalently to this one, but without
>   adding any padding character at the end of the encoded byte data.
>   Wraps an output stream for encoding byte data using the Base64
>   encoding scheme.
>
> **What is base64 encoding in Java?**
>   Base64 is a binary-to-text encoding scheme that represents binary data in a printable ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation. Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of binary data.Dec 6, 2017

Here is a link to Sun's Page on the issue:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html